# Ubuntu 12.04 3D loads when booting from usb but not after install

Tags: unity, 3d

So I was trying to install Ubuntu on my Samsung Q230 laptop. At first when I boot from Live USB it loads Unity 3D.

I checked with :

`echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` it says ubuntu.

Also for the unity support test it confirmed that my laptop can run 3D.

However after installing, it only loads 2D and when I try to run the unity support test it says `glx missing`. Why is it like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the proprietary drivers to enable 3D.  They are not installed by default because they are well, proprietary, but there is a something like a "fair use" clause that allows them to be used with Ubiquity.  Open additional drivers and get it to search for drivers for your graphics card.  You will probably have to log out and back in to use the drivers (or maybe re-boot).

[image]

If this doesn't work, find out what your graphics card is by opening a terminal a type:

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

Maybe search askubuntu based on the information you get from lshw, and add the information back into your question above.

Comment: hi thanks for answering. my laptop uses nvidia GeForce 310m so after checking out related posts i find that it is the nvidia-current which is problematic. i removed it in the software center and my unity 3D is back!!! though the effects seem to be a little bit laggy... anyways thanks for answering!!! :)